# Import error from mysql command line

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, command-line

[image]

I tried so many ways to restore a sample database (with the command on top of the picture) but i failed every single time. i successfully restored with this command in past. but now i am facing this problem. And when i am putting "\" to specify path, there is an error saying '\s' is not a valid command. You can see it's showing "D:ample.sql" :(

Comment: change it for d:/sample.sql

Comment: and!!! what the mysql> at the begin of string?

Comment: `mysqld` is the _server_; you need a _client_ to do the operation.

Answer (score 1):

look like You try to run mysql(?d) from inside mysql console
this command must be run from OS command line:

```
c:\Program Files\MySQL\bin>mysql -u root -p sample < d:/sample.sql
```

all from Windows command line

Comment: shouldn't he use path like this `d:\sample.sql`?

Comment: i tried both forward and backward slash but both failed.... and also from both mysql and windows command line.... still the same....... :(

Comment: Thanks a_vlad and Ahmed Abuhasna, both of you were right. :) the problem is solved. thanks to you guys :) Thanks a lot......

Answer (score 1):

since you are already logged in into MySQL then you need to inter the following command to read and execute text file

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'd:/sample.sql' INTO TABLE mytable;
```

OR you can quit your MySQL session and execute the command

```
c:\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p sample < d:\sample.sql
```

Notes: if you use the first method you may get the following error message:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

To fix it you need to add the following line into `my.ini` file and restart the service:

```
secure_file_priv=""
```

Comment: Thanks a_vlad and Ahmed Abuhasna, both of you were right. :) the problem is solved. thanks to you guys :) Thanks a lot........